# Parsing Excel Binary Workbook file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am having a heavy excel workbook with many sheets and loads of data and formulas and the file has a extension of `xlsb` (Excel Binary Workbook files store information in binary format ).  I am currently using [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) in my application to parse `xlsx` which works fine.

Any suggestions how can i parse this `xlsb` without converting it into a CSV or xlsx

Comment: I don't think it's possible with any currently available solutions...

Comment: I would like to know how you can convert xlsb to CSV or xlsx with Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet). I've had good luck with it in the past.